# Unexpected outputs from two different ways of adding an ArrayList to another

Tags: java

In some program as following:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I want to add temp into result, if I use

```
result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(temp));
```

then the final output is correct, but if I use

```
result.add(temp);
```

then my final output is wrong. Why? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please show your expectations and your actual results.

Comment: It may be that you are modifying `temp` after adding it to `result`? You are not creating a copy just by adding it to `result`, so you would need the first version to make the copy.

Comment: I think SJuan76 is right, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call:

```
result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(temp));
```

`temp` is copied into a new ArrayList and the end-result will contain the "untouched" copy.

By calling:

```
result.add(temp)
```

you're adding `temp` itself to the `result` so the actions you'll preform later-on on `temp` will be reflected in `result` (that's the unwanted behavior you described).

Comment: I checked the Java API, "new ArrayList<Integer>(temp)" Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection(temp), in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

Comment: @SaintHill I think that you missed something in the question - he defined `result` and `temp` correctly.

Comment: @alfasin (1) Your comment that my code does not compile below is bogus. (2) There is no unwanted behaviour described in the question. The user does not describe what is wrong with their final output.

Comment: @SaintHill indeed he does not describe *what* is wrong with the output but from his description about *wanted result* vs. `actual result` it's pretty obvious.

Comment: @alfasin Then why do people upvote this "Please show your expectations and your actual results."? Because it is not clear and it is not safe to assume. The question is not clear.

Comment: @SaintHill are you suggesting that I'm a psychic ? :D

Comment: Yes. You are psychic. That has got to be worth a few more points here :D

Answer (score 0):

### The question does not show what is actually wrong and what the desired output is supposed to be.

This, `result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(temp))`, and this, `result.add(temp)` will both produce the same contents in `result`

Without understanding clearly the desired output, I cannot see what is actually wrong with the code.

Further, it is better practice to refer to the ArrayList as a `List` on the left side and use the `<>` diamond on the right. Make your coding easier and clearer:

```
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    temp.add(1);
    temp.add(2);
    result.add(temp);
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

The output is exactly as specified and is a `List<List<Integer>>`:

> Result: [[1, 2]]

Comment: It would cause a compile error, because it will be adding `Integer` to an `ArrayList` that accepts `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: I meant that the compile error would happen if the OP was using `addAll`, so it should be discarded as the cause of the error. You have added more code, but the error still exists in your answer.

Comment: -1 not only that you don't answer the question, your code cannot be compiled. Further, if you'll try to do `List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();` you'll get a compilation error since generics is invariant. So by declaring `result` as `List<List<Integer>>` you make it impossible to be used.

Comment: @alfasin What version of Java are you using? I checked again and it has no problem compiling and running on mine by just copy/past the code snippet I posted.

Comment: I was running on Java 6. Yes it compiles - my bad (-1 removed even though you didn't answer the question).